# When submitting an app on app store for cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

When you submit your app, do you have to have the pictures inside your project folder or can you have the pictures on desktop and just use the build phase to save them. I submit my app without the pictures in my project folder and was wondering if it will get denied now.

Comment: You do not include the pictures within your project folder. Those are submitted separately into iTunes Connect when entering all the metadata connected to your App.

Comment: @Till I think he means the images used in the app.

Comment: So if i have the pictures on my desktop everything will be ok right?

Comment: Yeah, I mean images use in my app.

Comment: @MooMoo, even in that case I don't think you need to do anything. XCode must have copied them when you had achieved the project.

Comment: So, you think if i have the pictures for my game on my desktop rather than inside my game will still work?

Comment: If your app works and there are no missing images, it works. To be sure, delete the app from your device and run it again. That way you can be sure that everything that's supposed to be in the app is in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the images used in your app, then they're all gonna be inside the .ipa file that you submit to the app store. So on that left sidebar where all the class files for your views are, you have your picture files as well. When you choose the "Build" option to submit to the app store, all those files are included in the final version, which is the single .ipa file you submit. The only things you need to submit separately are the picture used on your app store page, so basically the screenshots of your app. Those get added through iTunes Connect.

In short, run it on the simulator. All the pictures there? Good. You're good to go :)